# How to prevent QMenu from going out of the main window

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qmenubar

I have a `QMenubar` inside `QMainWindow`. I have set it to be displayed on the right corner using `setCornerWidget`. But the menu items are going out of the main window. How can I prevent the menu to be displayed within the window?

[image]

I have already tried `menu->setLayoutDirection(Qt::RightToLeft)` which is giving me a mirror image of the current menu display as seen below, but that does not look good to me. Is there a way to keep the direction from `Qt::LeftToRight` and still be able to contain the menu inside the window?

[image]

Comment: You could show a picture of what you want to get. I will also propose an extreme case: Let's say that the width of the menu is larger than that of the window. What should happen in that case?

Comment: Have never met such possibility in Qt. Why do you need it? Actually you can manage the menu position and size by your code, but it may be a complicated thing.

Comment: Did you try using style sheets? using move or mapToGlobal? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal